# How to display Widget based on location service enabled or not in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my app i have to display two different widgets **based on location service** which is on or off.

So in my app i have to **display data widget if location is on**,

and if **location is off then display location off widget**.

Here i have to make screen which **automatically display data widget if location service is on** and if **i off the location service of device then it automatically displays location off widget** so how i can do this?

For Example show below Code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bluetooth Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
```

as above code if bluetooth is off then its shows BluetoothOffScreen() an if bluetooth is on then its display FindDevicesScreen() so here i have to do like this with location is on or off.

Please help me,
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get this "then it automatically displays location off widget"?

Comment: show some code of what you have tried

Comment: Okay i will put example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Permission handler package](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to check if the location services is enabled or not

```
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = await PermissionHandler().checkServiceStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
bool enabled = (serviceStatus == ServiceStatus.enabled);
```

and then based on the enabled bool value you can show or hide the widgets you want

Comment: yes i can try this but when i off the location then it can automatically shows the location off widget?

Comment: No, you have to check permission whenever screen is appear/visible.

Comment: No it is not reactive, you can either check permission whenever screen is appear/visible like Chirag said or execute this function periodically.